# Color X axis in ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would need help in order to color the x axis of a ggplot2 figure.

Here is what I can manage to do so far :

```
    head(data)
  x  y group Axis_color
1 A 25     F         G1
2 A 88     G         G1
3 A 88     H         G1
4 A 22     I         G1
5 A 18     J         G1
6 B 54     F         G3

color_list<- c("F"="orange", "G"="darkgreen", "H"="grey", "I"="pink", "J"="purple", "G1"="blue","G2"="red","G3"="green")
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group, label = y)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Which gives:

[image]

But I would like to as the column "Axis_color" in order to add colors stored in the `color_list` to the x axis and get:

[image]

As you can see I get two different legends axis as well.

Here are the data if it can helps :

```
structure(list(x = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E"), y = c(25, 88, 88, 22, 18, 54, 25, 37, 68, 
72, 36, 84, 17, 64, 48, 15, 17, 72, 61, 25, 66, 10, 18, 99, 63
), group = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J"), Axis_color = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G3", 
"G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most convenient solution I could come up with that includes a legend would be to use `geom_text()` to place fake axis labels. If the legend isn't needed I would've recommended [ggtext](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/index.html#markdown-in-theme-elements).

By placing the text at `x = -Inf`, you place it at the axis' minimum and you can further nudge the text to the outside with `hjust`. You'd need to turn off clipping in the coordinates for this to work. Alternatively you can also set `x = -10` or something, but you'd have to adjust the scale limits and tailor this value to every plot.

```r
# data <- structure(...) # omitted for brevity

library(ggplot2)

color_list<- c("F"="orange", "G"="darkgreen", "H"="grey", "I"="pink", "J"="purple", "G1"="blue","G2"="red","G3"="green")

ggplot(data, aes(x = y, y = x, fill = group, label = x)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(data = ~ subset(.x, !duplicated(x)),
            aes(x = -Inf, colour = Axis_color), hjust = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list[1:5]) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = color_list[-c(1:5)]) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = NA))
```

[image]

Small sidenote: I replaced `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` with `geom_col()` as that seems cleaner, and swapped the x and y aesthetics, removing the need for `coord_flip()`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of the `ggtext` package which allows to color the axis labels via some HTML/CSS.

To get a second legend I make use of the ggnewscale package as in the approach by @teunbrand. However, to make this work we have to add a second `geom`, too. To this end I added a helper `geom_col` where I set `y=0`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

color_list <- c("F"="orange", "G"="darkgreen", "H"="grey", "I"="pink", "J"="purple", "G1"="blue","G2"="red","G3"="green")
axis_color <- dplyr::distinct(data, x, Axis_color) %>% 
  tibble::deframe()

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group, label = y)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list, limits = force, guide = guide_legend(order= 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ glue::glue("<span style='color: {color_list[axis_color[.x]]}'>{.x}</span>")) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(aes(y = 0, fill = Axis_color)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list[unique(data$Axis_color)], guide = guide_legend(order= 2)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]